# Create tables of means and export them to LaTeX

Tags: export, latex, stata

I am using the following code to create tables in Stata:

```
sysuse auto, clear
table rep78, contents(mean mpg mean weight)

--------------------------------------
Repair    |
Record    |
1978      |    mean(mpg)  mean(weight)
----------+---------------------------
        1 |           21         3,100
        2 |       19.125       3,353.8
        3 |      19.4333         3,299
        4 |      21.6667         2,870
        5 |      27.3636       2,322.7
--------------------------------------
```

How can I directly export such tables in `LaTeX` markup?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a very simple working example of using the *community-contributed* command `texdoc`:

```
/* Create sample data */
clear *
set obs 10
gen date = _n
expand 10
set seed 123
gen i = runiform()
cd "/path/to/my/output"

/* Initialize and create LaTeX document */
texdoc init TexTest, replace

tex \documentclass{article}
tex \usepackage{stata}
tex \begin{document}

tex \section{Table 1}

texdoc stlog TexLog
table date, contents(mean i)

texdoc stlog close

tex \end{document}
```

The above code snippet creates `TexTest.tex` at `/path/to/my/output/`.

I use `texdoc stlog` before submitting the `table` command to capture the output of `table` in the log file. If you open the resulting `tex` file you will notice there is a line that has `\input{TexLog.log.tex}`. The compiler will insert the contents of the log file at that location in the `LaTeX` document.

You can compile the `tex` file using your preferred method. I use `pdflatex` in a Linux environment but had issues after initially installing it and had to resolve some dependencies for `stata.sty`.

After compiling, the resulting `pdf` file will contain the following table:

[image: Resulting PDF output]

Comment: Ive been trying to test a similar approach but every time i try to compile it i run across the same error --> Package csvsimple Error: File 'libro1' not existent, not readable, or empty!. \csvautotabular{libro1}. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{frame}
Variacion producto versus Variacion IPC
\csvautotabular{libro1} 
\end{frame}
 
\end{document}`

Comment: To me that looks like an issue with the csvsimple package - or possibly not the package itself, but libro1. Is libro1 a csv file you are trying to load? is it in the same directory as the .tex file? I'm not a tex expert, but I'd start by looking at the csvsimple package or possible issues surrounding your use of `\csvautotabular`. On a side note, were you able to test with the code in the answer to verify things are working properly otherwise?

Comment: @BegStata I just tested with a sample file titled libro1.csv, and got the error. I resolved it by adding the .csv extension to `\csvautotabular{libro1.csv}`. perhaps that is all you need to do. Otherwise, this sounds like a separate question that should be posted on http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you @ander2ed! I already tried doing that and unfortunately I was still getting that error. I appreciate your help anyways!!

Comment: No problem. Based on the error you cited, you likely have an issue surrounding the file you are trying to read itself. Whether the issue is that the file isn't in the appropriate directory, or if the file somehow does not meet the expectations of the csvsimple package. Perhaps view it in a text editor and see if you can spot any abnormalities in the file itself. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The *community-contributed* command `tabout` provides an out-of-the-box solution:

```
. tabout rep78 using table.tex, style(tex) content(mean mpg mean weight) sum replace

Table output written to: table.tex

\begin{center}
\footnotesize
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{tabularx} {14} {@{} l Y Y @{}}
\toprule
 & mpg & weight \\
\midrule 
Repair Record 1978 \\
1 & 21.0 & 3,100.0 \\
2 & 19.1 & 3,353.8 \\
3 & 19.4 & 3,299.0 \\
4 & 21.7 & 2,870.0 \\
5 & 27.4 & 2,322.7 \\
Total & 21.3 & 3,032.0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\normalsize
\end{center}
```